# Treeview Imageindex - image keeps changing

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-xe2

How do I keep a Treeview from reverting to the first image in an image list when a node is selected? When the Group nodes are created, they have an ImegeIndex of 1

```
  Node := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, 'Software');
  Node.ImageIndex:=1;
```

However, when I expand the node it appears the ImageIndex changes to 0 and a different image is displayed.  Any idea how to fix that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The image displayed for the node when it is selected is determined by the SelectedIndex property, So you must set the [`SelectedIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.SelectedIndex) property value to the same of the `ImageIndex`.

```
Node.SelectedIndex:=Node.ImageIndex;
```

Comment: Thank you so very much.  What would I do without this site?  Thanks